# How to make output of one git command result as input parameter of another git result?

Tags: awk, git

I am using following for getting a git Commit ID:

```
git log -1 --oneline | awk '{print $1}
```

and suppose i am getting 123456 as commit id output

but now i want to use this id like this:

```
git log 123456
```

how can i get this all in a single line command?

Answer (score 2):

By running it as sub command:

```
git log $(git log -1 --oneline | awk '{print $1}')
```